# post a file which is there on remote linux machine in python

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

I have a large file which is there on a remote Linux machine. Since the file is too big, I cannot store it on my local windows machine. Is there any way that I can POST this remote file to server directly? Here the remote Linux machine do has the username and password.

I have the code below to POST the local file i.e., bin_file_name:

```
system_update_file = {'file': (bin_file_name, open(str(bin_file_name), 'rb'), multipart/form-data')}
with requests.Session() as s:
   resp = s.post(request_url, params=None, files=system_update_file , auth=(amc_username_api, amc_password), verify=False)
```

How to use the code above to POST the remote file to server?

Comment: Do you want to transfer a file from a remote machine to another remote machine?

Comment: No. Basically I need to upload a file from a remote machine to WEB Server from a windows machine using POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just shared that file using network share via Samba. The below code did the job for me:

```
bin_file_path = "//remote_linux_machine_ip/folder/subfolder/actual_bin_file.bin"
system_update_file = {'file': (bin_file_path, open(str(bin_file_path), 'rb'), multipart/form-data')}
with requests.Session() as s:
  resp = s.post(request_url, params=None, files=system_update_file , auth=(amc_username_api, amc_password), verify=False)
```